# Trying to add date from Firebase to ListView but my app keeps crashing

Tags: android, firebase

I've been trying to add data from my Firebase Database to a ListView and it just seems to crash my app.

Here is my code:

```
public class ReadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView l1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
Players info;
List<String> itemList;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading);

    l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            itemList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                info = items.getValue(Players.class);
                itemList.add("Player Goals: " + info.playerGoals);
                itemList.add("Player Points: " + info.playerPoints);


            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ReadingActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            l1.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is some error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

}

The code above shows no errors, but it keeps crashing. Does anyone have any idea how I might fix this?

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: can you show your log cat??

Comment: Please add your logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that the problem with the adapter

To use a basic `ArrayAdapter`, you just need to initialize the adapter :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ReadingActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
```

The `ArrayAdapter` requires three arguments: `context` (activity instance), `XML` item layout, and the array of data.

I don't know if it's it as you don't know the actual error